# I am solving below problem but all test cases not getting pass in java

Tags: java

There are a number of genes in a chromosome and your bioinformatic friend wants to check if a particular chromosome has a series of genes or not. 
The sequence in which genes occur is important. You want to help your friend in this matter. 
He gives you n chromosomes and a series of genes he wants to check. Help him identify whether these genes are present in the 
chromosome in the given order.

Because you are not a biology student, he’s made things easier for you. He represents genes by a letter, number or special character present in ASCII. 
Spaces do NOT represent a gene.

**Example**

If the chromosome is `abdfgc`, and the genes he’s querying for is `abc`, these are present (in the correct order) in the chromosome (marked in bold). 
`a*b*dfg*c*`. However if the query is `bca`, this is not present in the correct order in the chromosome.

**Input**

The first line of input consists of an integer `n` which is the number of test cases.

Each test case consists of two lines of input:

- The first line contains the chromosome
- The second line contains the gene you are querying for
  Output

The output for that chromosome-gene pair should be “YES” if the genes, taken in order, are contained in the chromosome and “NO” otherwise. 
The output should have n lines containing YES/NO.

**Constraints**

```
1 <= n <= 10000

1 <= |chromosome| <100

1 <= |gene| < |chromosome|
```

**Sample Input**

```
4
12sd78f
sf
12345efd
1e3d
ijkfgds
jkf
1111456
116
```

**Sample Output**

```
YES
NO
YES
YES
```

**Code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class solution {

private static String checkGem(String ch, String gem) {

    int prevIndex = 0;
    for(int n=0; n < gem.length(); n++) {
        if(ch.indexOf(gem.charAt(n), prevIndex)==-1) {
            return "NO";
        }
        else {
            prevIndex = ch.indexOf(gem.charAt(n), prevIndex);
        }
    }

    return "YES";
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String test = br.readLine();    

    int t = Integer.parseInt(test);

    for(int i=0; i<t; i++) {
        String ch = br.readLine();
        String gem = br.readLine();
        ch = ch.replaceAll("\\s","");
        gem =  gem.replaceAll("\\s","");
        String ans = checkGem(ch, gem);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger, where does it not do what you expected?

Comment: I did launch you code and all works well.  Give an example of the test, that does not pass correctly.

Comment: `prevIndex + 1` do not start next search from the same place

Comment: where are you having problems

Comment: I dont have test cases, only output i am getting as test case failed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code. You can try this test case:

```
1
a
aaaaa
```

This one should be "NO", but your code output is "YES".

The problem is that you need to advance `prevIndex` it should be:

```
prevIndex = ch.indexOf(gem.charAt(n), prevIndex) + 1;
```